# extract words of length >= 4 from 100k words

Tags: python

I've got a file that is ONE line with about 100,000 words all in one line.

How can I extract only the words that are of length greater or equal to 4 the fastest and most efficient way?

I thought about using regex to do so but I am not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: How is the file delimited?

Comment: The file is one line with words spaced apart in alphabetical order. ex: `a aa aab abass...` @JoachimIsaksson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `re` over the `mmap`'d file.., eg:

```
import mmap, re

with open('somefile') as fin:
    mf = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    words = re.findall('\w{4,}', mf)
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than `[word for word in line.split() if len(word) >= 4]`? they have the same output. Would using regex be fast than `len()`?

Comment: @Liondancer you'd have to `timeit` them... They have slightly different behaviour in what goes on underneath the hood... my suspicion is that the list-comp is possibly faster, but the regex/mmap approach is more flexible...

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension would work well:

```
[word for word in line.split() if len(word) >= 4]
```

Comment: shouldn't that "where" be "if"?

Comment: if any punctuation, you should add:
import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
line = ''.join(ch for ch in line if ch not in exclude)

Answer (score 1):

Are they space separated?  You could just use csv reader with the delimiter set to space and then just loop it where len() >= 4.

Better might be to use the custom newline file iterator from [this feature request](http://bugs.python.org/msg109117) and set newline to ' '.  (You can follow the link for the code for `fileLineIter()`).

```
f = open(filename,'rb')
for word in fileLineIter(f,' ',' '):
    if len(word) >=4:
        do_something()
```